# Origin of "forecast"

Tags: etymology

According to **[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/forecast?s=t)**

> **forecast**[fawr-kast, -kahst, fohr-]
>
> **verb** (used with object), forecast or forecasted, forecasting.
>
> 1. to predict (a future condition or occurrence); calculate in advance
>
>    *to forecast a heavy snowfall; to forecast lower interest rates.*
> 2. to serve as a prediction of; foreshadow.
> 3. to contrive or plan beforehand; prearrange.
>
> **verb** (used without object), forecast or forecasted, forecasting.
>
> 4.to conjecture beforehand; make a prediction.
>
> 5.to plan or arrange beforehand.
>   noun
>
> 6.a prediction, especially as to the weather.
>
> 7.a conjecture as to something in the future.
>
> 8.the act, practice, or faculty of forecasting.
>
> 9.Archaic. foresight in planning.

According to **[Online Etymology dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=fore&searchmode=none)**, fore- has an etymology of Middle-English but [**Cast**](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=cast&searchmode=none) doesn't have a known origin. [**Forecast**](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=forecast&searchmode=none) doesn't have a known origin either.

So what is the origin of the word *forecast*?

Comment: Check [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=forecast&searchmode=none) again.

Comment: @StoneyB As you can see above in my definitions, I am doing the verb forecast.

Comment: @StoneyB I hope you can realize and read through. There is no language referral as the origin.

Comment: @StoneyB Already been there AND mentioned it in my question

Comment: So what is missing that isn't given in those locations?

Comment: cast(v) doesn't have an origin

Comment: What are you asking here? Ther's no question.

Comment: @Mitch Yes there is. It's in the title and my question

Comment: @anonymous What is it about the etymonline entry that doesn't answer your question?

Comment: @Mitch There was just some confusion with StoneyB. StoneyB assumed I was asking about the noun which has a clear origin. It is the verb I am asking about which according to etymonline, has no definite origin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Etymonline derives *forecast* from two English words, *fore-* and *cast*.

*Fore-* is  derived by the *American Heritage Dictionary of Indo-European Roots* from the conjecturally reconstructed PIE *per*,

> Base of prepositions with the basic meanings of "forward", "through"

via conjecturally reconstructed Germanic, **fura*, before.

Etymonline identifies *cast* as cognate with Swedish *kasta*, Danish *kaste*, North Frisian *kastin*, "of uncertain origin". [*OED 1*](http://archive.org/stream/oed02arch#page/154/mode/2up) provides a few more apparent cognates from North Germanic and invites comparison with

> *kös* (*kasu*),*köstr* (:—*kastuz*), pile, heap thrown up, which has been compared with L. *gerĕre* (*ges-*) *gestus*.

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cast#Etymology) offers a conjecturally reconstructed verb from Proto-Germanic:

> from Proto-Germanic **kastōną* ‎(“to throw, cast”), of unknown origin.

*AHDIER* does not index *cast*, and the [online database to Pokorny](http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/query.cgi?basename=%5Cdata%5Cie%5Cpokorny&) appears to offer no term from which *cast* is derived, suggesting that no one has convincingly pushed the origin of *cast* farther back than common Germanic.